# Create Subscription in a Topic programatically using Windows Azure Service Bus REST API

Tags: rest, azure, azureservicebus

Is it possible to create a Subscription in an existing Topic programmatically in Azure Service Bus using the REST API?

I would like to create one on the fly and then delete programmatically as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Please look at the REST API documentation here:

Create Subscription: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780748.aspx

Delete Subscription: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780740.aspx

For a full list of REST API operation on Service Bus: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780776.aspx.

Comment: There has to be an easier way to do this with C# and nuget packages surely?

Comment: You can through Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60957230/591097