# How to create windows azure subscription from api

Tags: azure

I am successfully using [Service Management REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx) for management of my virtual machines, clouds, storage etc. I am using this API of course through wrappers (Microsoft Azure Management Libraries). The main problem is that there are limits for subscription (for example 20 cores per it). An in some cases, after peek load I need to create more virtual machines than this limit. So the main question is are there any  programmatic interface for https://account.windowsazure.com so I could dynamically create new subscription and use it for all new virtual machines over this limit?

I have found similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665243/create-subscription-in-a-topic-programatically-using-windows-azure-service-bus-r)
but seem to me it is not related to account.windowsazure.com.

Comment: The quota is there to prevent beginners from accidentally scaling out to gazillion instances. Once you're got used to Azure you can contact support and ask to increase your quota. I guess filing a billing ticket would work if you don't have a support plan.

Comment: We just announced the public preview for this feature. Please take a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/programmatically-create-enterprise-subscriptions-preview/

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is that you can't create a subscription programmatically. You will have to create it manually.

If your issue is with subscription limits, you can always contact support to get your quota increased.

Comment: I wish they had chosen any other name,. subscription is very ambigious to what a user may intend to use it for,.. in this case the OP isn't asking about the servicebus, but the actual azure platform.  And yeah,. no go. He'll have to manually do that - after all thats linked to your account.