# Create filtered Service Bus subscription using .NET Core SDKs

Tags: azure, .net-core, azureservicebus

I want to use Azure Service Bus from inside an .NET Core 2.1 application. I'm familiar with the SDK coming with the Nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` and using this I'm currently writing to a topic and receiving messages from there.

What I want now is to create subscriptions on this topic for every client. The point is that I want to create a filtered subscription using the `SqlFilter`. This means, I have to create the subscription by code.

BTW: As far as I've seen it the only other way then doing it in code is using ARM template for the deployment because the portal will not allow me to create a filtered subscription.

I understood, that `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` is not able to create ressources and so I went to the Nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus`. So I now can create a new subscription from code now like this:

```cs
private static async Task CreateSubscriptionAsync()
{
    var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AppSettings:AzureManagement:TenantId"]}");
    var token = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(
        "https://management.core.windows.net/",
        new ClientCredential(Configuration["AppSettings:AzureManagement:ClientId"], Configuration["AppSettings:AzureManagement:ClientSecret"]));
    var creds = new TokenCredentials(token.AccessToken);
    using (var sbClient = new ServiceBusManagementClient(creds)
    {
        SubscriptionId = VariableHelper.Configuration["AppSettings:AzureManagement:AzureSubscriptionId"]
    })
    {                
        var queueParams = new SBSubscription
        {
            LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };          
        await sbClient.Subscriptions.CreateOrUpdateAsync(
            Configuration["AppSettings:ServiceBus:ResourceGroup"],
            Configuration["AppSettings:ServiceBus:Namespace"],
            Configuration["AppSettings:ServiceBus:TopicName"],
            "mysub",
            queueParams);                
    }
}
```

This works so I have a new subscription which I'm also able to delete. But now where can I define the filter? The `SBSubscription`-type contains no option to define a filter and there is no method-overload in `sbClient.Subscriptions.CreateOrUpdateAsync`.

The only way I found to do this in code is based on the old Nuget `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` which is not available for .NET Core. So there I would use a `NamespaceManager` like this:

```cs
var manager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("MyConnectionString");            
var rule = new RuleDescription("property > 4");
var sub = manager.CreateSubscriptionAsync(new SubscriptionDescription("mytopic", "mysub"), rule);
```

Without this feature the complete topic-thing seems to be very useless to me and I can't believe that this means that Azure Service Bus is simply not ready for .NET Core.

**Edit: Solution as suggested by Arunprabhu**

I just wanted to present the solution in complete.

1. Add reference to NuGet `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus`.
2. Add reference to NuGet `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`.
3. Create the sub as follows:

```cs
private static async Task CreateSubscriptionAsync()
{
    // this is to show that it works with any subscription-name
    var subName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");     
    // create the subscription using Azure Management API
    var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AppSettings:AzureManagement:TenantId"]}");
    var token = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(
        "https://management.core.windows.net/",
        new ClientCredential(Configuration["AppSettings:AzureManagement:ClientId"], Configuration["AppSettings:AzureManagement:ClientSecret"]));
    var creds = new TokenCredentials(token.AccessToken);
    using (var sbClient = new ServiceBusManagementClient(creds)
    {
        SubscriptionId = VariableHelper.Configuration["AppSettings:AzureManagement:AzureSubscriptionId"]
    })
    {                
        var queueParams = new SBSubscription
        {
            LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };          
        await sbClient.Subscriptions.CreateOrUpdateAsync(
            Configuration["AppSettings:ServiceBus:ResourceGroup"],
            Configuration["AppSettings:ServiceBus:Namespace"],
            Configuration["AppSettings:ServiceBus:TopicName"],
            subName,
            queueParams);                
    }
    // add filter-rule using Azure ServiceBus API
    var client = new SubscriptionClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, Configuration["AppSettings:ServiceBus:TopicName"], subName);
    await client.AddRuleAsync("default", new SqlFilter("1=1"));
    // That's it        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expounding on Sean Feldman's answer since his example link is now broken, you can do something like this:

```cs
public static async Task CreateSubscription(
        string connection,
        string topicPath,
        string subscriptionName,
        string matchExpression,
        string ruleDescription,
        bool checkForExisting = false,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if (checkForExisting)
    {
        var exists = (await new ManagementClient(connection)
            .GetSubscriptionsAsync(topicPath, cancellationToken: cancellationToken))
            .Any(sub => sub.SubscriptionName == subscriptionName);

        if (exists) return;
    }

    var subscriptionDescription = new SubscriptionDescription(topicPath, subscriptionName);
    var rule = new RuleDescription(ruleDescription, new SqlFilter(matchExpression));
    await new ManagementClient(connection).CreateSubscriptionAsync(subscriptionDescription, 
        rule, 
        cancellationToken);
}
```

For simplicity I've removed the obligatory input validations like empty strings or non-valid characters. I've also included a way to check whether the subscription already exists. Ideally you'd only perform that check once, then keep a running tab in memory so you're not performing that API call each time.

For your `matchExpression` you'd define the filter for that subscription in SQLish syntax, based on user properties that were added to the message when it was published.
The implementation would look something like:

```cs
await CreateSubscription(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyServiceBusConnectionString"),
    "myTopicName",
    "mySubscription",
    "MyUserProperty='MyValue'",
    "MyRule",
    true
)
```

Answer (score 5):

> I understood, that Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus is not able to create ressources

As of version 3.1.0-preview of [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/3.1.0-preview) you can create entities using `ManagementClient` without the need in the Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus library. It has an overload of `CreateSubscriptionAsync()` that takes in `RuleDescription` to be created as the default rule. Alternatively, providing no `RuleDescription` will set up a default rule for you automatically.

Comment: could you point to an example of that `ManagementClient`? I was only able to find this, which still depends on the Management.ServiceBus libs: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-management/blob/a55185bef30d1763c1a8182a3361dbb548bad436/src/service-bus-dotnet-management/ServiceBusManagementSample.cs

Comment: Here's an [example](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Transport.AzureServiceBus/blob/develop/src/Transport/Administration/QueueCreator.cs#L44). Conceptually it's not that different from the old `NamespaceManager`.

Answer (score 2):

There are similar methods available for rules management under SubscriptionClient in Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus. Look [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus) for samples.

Comment: As far as I understand the samples they are showing creation of subscriptions using ARM templates and then usage of those "static" subscriptions. What I want is to create a filtered subscription "on demand". So when a client session is opened a subscription an an existing topic is created and later on deleted by my source code.

Comment: I think the only option using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus is to create rules on the already created subscriptions. You can create a Subscription using ServiceBusManagementClient of Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus and add rules using SubscriptionClient of Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus

Comment: The last point cleared it out. I missed `CreateRuleAsync` on `SubscriptionClient`.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* create filters with the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus` package, they're part of [Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.irulesoperations?view=azure-dotnet).

```cs
await client.Rules.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, namespaceName, 
    topicName, subscriptionName, filterName, new Rule {
    SqlFilter = new SqlFilter(sql)
});
```

You see the filter name and SQL string in the screenshot below from the Azure Portal:

[image]